# Clarification regarding shell script scheduling

Tags: bash, shell

I have 2 shell scripts say a.sh and b.sh  scheduled in cron where the first one a.sh is scheduled to run at 5am and the second script b.sh will run at 7am.

There are  pre-conditions which state that :

```
1) Only one can run at a time.
2) The second script b.sh should run only after the first script a.sh completes.
```

Now the problem is the first script a.sh may complete its execution before 7am or may exceed 7am in some cases and in the case where it exceeds 7am the second script is also started which will break one of the pre-conditions.

Here I cannot start the second script later that day as its very crucial script.

Here how can I make both the scripts run one after the other without the first script stepping on the second script.

Comment: Write a wrapper script that runs `a.sh`, check if the current time is within the valid range and runs `b.sh` in that case?

Comment: So what you are suggesting is schedule a wrapper script at 5am to run the first script and after the exec for the first script is done and if the current time is > 7am then start the second script too.Is that correct?

Comment: Seems like you have a catch 22. a must run at 5 && can run past 7. b must run at 7, but can not run while a is running. Trivial to have them run sequentially or at a certain time, but you still need to lax your parameters somewhere.

Comment: @Dark Matter: Yes. Depening on the timing constraints, you can use the [at](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_%28Unix%29) utility to schedule the run of `b.sh` at the correct time.

Notice that I interpreted your question as _b should run if a is completed in less than two hours_ - i.e. if the time is < 7am when a is complete.

Comment: @Anders Lindahl: So what you are suggesting is schedule the wrapper script at 5am and run the first script and after completion of the execution if the time is greater than 7am run the second script and if the time is lesser than 7am schedule the second script to run at 7am using `at`.Is that right?

Comment: Use a lockfile. If b.sh detects the lockfile reschedule itself for later.

Comment: @RedX : What is a lockfile, can you elaborate how to make use of it.

Comment: Google is definitely your friend here. A lockfile is a file that one application creates and another checks for existance. It's as simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

Have the a.sh script create a lockfile when it's complete (last line).

```
touch ~/a.lck
```

At the beginning of b.sh:

```
if [ ! -f ~/a.lck ]; then
  exit 1 #or whatever you want it to do if the lock file is not there.
fi
```

Don't forget to rm the lockfile either at the beginning of a.sh or the end of b.sh!